# online build servers?

Tags: build, build-process, build-automation, release-management, software-release

i'm a developer working with another developer geographically somewhere else, and we have to build software for mac osx 10.4 and windows xp sp2 and later. right now we each have our own laptops which do not have identical software installations on them, and we have a bunch of other nonrelated software installed.

does there exist some kind of build environment service in the cloud that lets you instantly create a win xp sp2 + mac osx 10.4 virtual machine with developer tools preinstalled that we could use as a "build server" somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/

We uploaded our build environments - works great.